# Finding substring in the list

Tags: python

I am learning python by looking and also trying to solve interview questions.

In the following question and solution is provided.

Given a non-empty string check if it can be constructed by taking a substring of it and appending multiple copies of the substring together. You may assume the given string consists of lowercase English letters only and its length will not exceed 10000.

**Example 1:**

Input: "abab"

Output: True

Explanation: It's the substring "ab" twice.

**Example 2:**

Input: "aba"

Output: False

```
def repeatedSubstringPattern2(self, str):
        """
        :type str: str
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if not str:
            return False

        ss = (str + str)[1:-1]
        print ss
        return ss.find(str) != -1
```

My question is even though aba is listed as a False example, but looking at the solution it gives me a sense that it is true. Any idea?? What I am missing?

```
  ss = (aba +aba)[1:-1] --> abaaba[1:-1] --> baaba 
  baaba.find(aba) != -1 --> true??
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but if you're learning python you should really learn python 3 instead of python 2.

Comment: There's plenty of issues with this, not least that `str` is a built-in

Comment: @roganjosh, what other issues that you have found?

Comment: @Aran-Fey, what will be advantages of learning python 3 over python 2?

Comment: @hotspring python 2 is no longer actively maintained, while python 3 will continue to be developed

Comment: If you're coming from another language then camelCase will stand out a lot. See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You're also clearly using python 2 where support will be discontinued soon

Comment: You'll have a better programming language, with a better standard library, and it won't reach end-of-life in 3 years like python 2 will. The question is really not *"What's the advantage of learning python 3"*; the question is *"What reason is there to still learn python 2?"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic you use in this line:

```
ss = (aba +aba)[1:-1] --> abaaba[1:-1] --> baaba
```

is incorrect. When you slice a list, it doesn't include the element at the second slicing index. The correct logic would be:

```
ss = (aba +aba)[1:-1] --> abaaba[1:-1] --> baab
```